# In Swagger , Is it possible to create API's for Websockets?

Tags: api, websocket

I dont know how to create a documentation for websockets in swagger. In Apairy does not have an option to create API's for Websockets. In Swagger, is it Possible to create means please justify .. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Not at the moment, you can follow the websocket discussion in this thread:

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/523

An alternative spec that supports websocket documentation is AsyncAPI:

https://github.com/asyncapi/asyncapi